# Line breaks with left and right rules

Tags: line-breaking, rules

Sometimes, not always, rules are -- like parentheses -- left and right.
The previous sentence exemplifies this.  In such cases, line breaks
oughtn't to separate the left rule from the word to the right of it, nor
the right from that to its left.  What would be a nice, clean, way of
following this rule?

To clarify, the first sentence should be breakable thus:

```
Sometimes, not always, rules are
-- like parentheses --
left and right.
```

But not thus:

```
Sometimes, not always, rules are --
like parentheses
-- left and right.
```

---

PS.

I think the cleanest way of doing this would be to write insertions
--the kind that are delimited by rules-- like this.  This would tell TeX
whether a rule is left or right.  That's not to say the typeset document
should have no space between rule and insertion; this could be
controlled by an option (as could whether to use em-rules).  (There are
in fact some very respectable books that use this asymmetrical style,
sc. from Oxford --mid 20th century-- and typeset by an
``architypographus''.)---But I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: What you have in mind is not very clear to me. Could post a sketch of what you have in mind?

Comment: @Bernard, done.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for the French language,  babel -french inserts a thin unbreakable space (`\,`) after the opening dash, and another one before the closing dash.

Comment: @Bernard, but how does it know which is which?

Comment: No idea. Maybe it is made an active character?

Comment: @Bernard, as far as I can understand, there is no way for the programme to know, since some rules are not -- left or right.

Comment: As I told you, I really don't know. Maybe they use a command for that. Personally, when I have to, I add thin spaces by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I overcome the natural tendency for en-dash linebreak by using `\char"7B` instead. (note: em-dash alternative is `\char"7C`)

In the MWE, by setting `\textwidth` to `0pt`, it forces linebreaks and hyphenation at every opportunity.  But we see it avoided after the opening en-dash and prior to the closing one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth 0pt

\begin{document}
Sometimes, not always, rules are \char"7B~like parentheses~-- left and right.

\end{document}
```

[image]

One could macrofy it as `\dashphrase`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dashphrase[1]{\char"7B~#1~--}
\begin{document}
\parbox[b]{163pt}{
Sometimes, not always, rules are \dashphrase{like parentheses} left and right.}

\parbox[t]{164pt}{
Sometimes, not always, rules are \dashphrase{like parentheses} left and right.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate definition like

```
\newcommand\dashphrase[2][7B]{\char"#1~#2~\char"#1 }
```

would allow an optional argument like `7C` to provide the em-dash, rather than the en-dash.

**SUPPLEMENT:**

Since the OP wants a left/right sense to the dashes (but not always), which cannot be clearly drawn from context, the only other way I can think of is to sacrifice 2 keyboard characters (made active) for this purpose.  Here I choose `<` and `>`, which will revert to their normal meanings in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svlb<
\let\svrb>
\catcode`\<=\active
\def<{\ifmmode\expandafter\svlb\else\char"7B ~\fi}
\catcode`\>=\active
\def>{\ifmmode\expandafter\svrb\else~\char"7B \fi}
\begin{document}

\parbox[b]{163pt}{
Sometimes, not always, rules are <like parentheses> left and right.}

\parbox[t]{164pt}{
Sometimes, not always, rules are <like parentheses> left and right.}

$a<b>c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by the natural tendency for .. ?

Comment: @Toothrot While `~` prevents a linebreak at the space, I found that `--~like...` did *not* prevent the linebreak after the en-dash.  That is (apparently) because the `--` itself naturally allows a trailing linebreak.  I could circumvent that by resorting to `\char"7B` in lieu of `--`.

Comment: I see.  I think it would be really great to find some way of changing
that behaviour (does it serve a purpose?) without typing something
different each time.  Tildes I could live with, but `\char` and
`\dashphrase` isn't something I'm very keen on having all over the
source.

Comment: @Toothrot I doubt you will find a satisfactory solution...you desire to use `--` in both a left and right handed sense, and to have it figure out the sense from the surrounding context. Very difficult if not impossible.  A macro like `\dashphrase` provides the context that allows it to function as expected.

Comment: @Toothrot To your question, "does it serve a purpose?", the answer is that linebreaking following a dash is standard grammar.

Comment: even if an insertion follows?  i didn't know that.

Comment: anyway, I suppose inserting a unicode en-rule on the left (instead of using `\char`) would be OK.

Comment: @Toothrot I'm sure you understood my misstatement that "linebreaking following a dash" is *conditional* to it occurring at the end of a line,  As to unicode, I don't use it enough to know if it will work for you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  the way I read your claim about standard grammar you were denying the standardness of the rule proposed in my question.

Comment: @Toothrot Please see my supplement.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `extdash` package. An example follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sic Sometimes, not always, rules are
\--- like parentheses \--- left and right. 

\end{document}
```

[image]