# An alternative way of processing asymmetrical en-rules

Tags: spacing, symbols, luatex

`--` is changed into an en-rule, by some mechanism.  In Lua(La)TeX, would it
be possible to use the same mechanism to change  `--` (space on the
left) into  `–~` (space on the
left)
and `--`  (space on the right) into `~–`  (space on the right)?

The target `~` should be a non-breaking space and not a tilde.
The source   should be any whitespace (space, tab, newline).

The purpose of this would be to get more sensible breaking around rules,
such that rule insertions --this kind-- would not be separated from
their rules.

The resulting style would be unusual, but I am sure the answer could
fairly easily be altered to get normal en-rules with space on both sides
or em-rules with space on neither.  The crucial thing for me is to avoid
breaking between the rule and the inserted phrase.  Using asymmetrical
rules in the source would be necessary to indicate which rule is left
and which is right.

I hope this was clear; if not, please see this question:

[Line breaks with left and right rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509211/line-breaks-with-left-and-right-rules)

Comment: I think I am using something simillar to that you require. Its rough, and I ma pretty much new around here, but could work for you. Think is, I am not using luaTeX, but luaLaTeX. That should not mind, I am just asking if it is ok. I am using luaTeX callbacks to change normal spaces to non-breaking ones.

Comment: @TomášKruliš, please show me.  I'm using LuaLaTeX too.

Comment: you could use the input buffer callback to modify the input

Comment: As mr. Carlisle said, I am doing exactly the same! Working on example right now.

Comment: I am sorry, for some reason I am having trouble to make work the substitution. I hope that @DavidCarlisle would be able to help you. Also, look at the doc of luatexbase, there are some information about input_buffer_callback. All you need is to modify it the right way (which I am having trouble to perform). I am using this callback to add non-breakable breaks in czech language.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This adds visible `[]` as well as non breakable space, just to highlight the insertions, adjust the macros to add whatever you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\directlua{
function dashes(s)
 return string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(s,
  '^\@percentchar-\@percentchar-', ' --'),
  '\@percentchar-\@percentchar-$', '-- '),
   '(\@percentchar s+)\@percentchar-\@percentchar-','\@percentchar 1--\string\\leftdashspace '),
   '\@percentchar-\@percentchar-(\@percentchar s+)','\string\\rightdashspace --\@percentchar 1')
end
}
\makeatother
\def\startscan{%
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dashes, "dashes")}}
\def\endscan{%
\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "dashes")}}

\setlength\textwidth{300pt}
\begin{document}


The purpose of this would be to get more sensible breaking around
--rules-- such that rule insertions --this kind-- would not be separated
from their rules
The purpose of this would be to get --more sensible-- breaking around
rules, such that rule insertions --this kind-- would --not be separated--
from their rules
The purpose of this would be to get more sensible breaking around
rules, such that rule insertions --this kind-- would not be separated
from their rules

\bigskip

\newcommand\leftdashspace{\nolinebreak\hspace{3pt}{[}}
\newcommand\rightdashspace{{]}\nolinebreak\hspace{3pt}}

\startscan

The purpose of this would be to get more sensible breaking around
--rules-- such that rule insertions --this kind-- would not be separated
from their rules
The purpose of this would be to get --more sensible-- breaking around
rules, such that rule insertions --this kind-- would --not be separated--
from their rules
The purpose of this would be to get more sensible breaking around
rules, such that rule insertions --this kind-- would not be separated
from their rules

\endscan

\end{document}
```